# jQuery UI Tab not working with cookies

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm using JQUERY UI TABS with Cookies to retain the tab but it's not working. Is this correct?

```
         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <script src="JS/jquery.cookies.2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        $("#tabs").tabs({ cookie: { expires: 30} });

        <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>

        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1"></div>
        <div id="tabs-2"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Have you referenced the [cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cookie) ?

Comment: Do you have cookies enabled in your browser? What exactly is not working?

Comment: Yes, i have referenced the cookie plugin from http://code.google.com/p/cookies/downloads/detail?name=jquery.cookies.2.2.0.min.js.zip&can=2&q=

Comment: Yes, cookies are enabled in my browser. When I have it as $("#tabs").tabs(); the tab shows the two tabs I have but when I include the cookies, it puts both tabs into one.

Comment: Paste a simplified version of your HTML that demonstrates the issue

Comment: It works! The cookie plugin I was using was not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the cookie plugin?

Note the dependencies on the jQuery UI [Tab documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#cookie):

> **Dependencies**
>
> ```
> UI Core
> UI Widget
> Optional: jquery.cookie.js for use with cookie option 
> (also included in development-bundle>external folder.)
> ```

This means that to use the cookie persistence features of jQuery UI tabs, you must also include the jquery.cookie.js JavaScript (above the jQuery UI JavaScript).

**For example**:

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If, after ensuring this is correct cookie persistence still fails, ensure you have [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) installed and include any error output in your original question.

Comment: Where did you find it? Not in my current JQuery distro (1.10.1)

Comment: @AskarIbragimov it looks like they've removed it from 1.10+ http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#removed-cookie-option

Comment: I run Firefox latest version and got the Tab cookies to work this way: Download Cookie plugin from here: http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/ . Then I used this site for the implementation of the cookie: http://www.bloodforge.com/post/jQuery-19-and-UI-110-tabs-with-cookies.aspx. Hope that helps anyone else in the future.